# unable to run Joomla on IIS7

Tags: php, joomla, iis-7

I'm having some problems getting a Joomla site running on my Windows 2008R2 machine with IIS 7.5.  First I installed from the Joomla package, the only problem I seemed to have was when the program tried to delete the install directory.  Then we tried to install the new site from a .jpa file., That failed with errors that the contents of the file could not be opened.  Next we just uploaded the necessary files and now we are getting

> Neither your session save path in your server's php.ini not the installation/tmp directory is writeable. One of them must be writable for the installation to continue.  Please try giving the installation/tmp directory 0777 permissions with your FTP programme and reload this page.

I don't believe that IIS supports 0777 style permissions and I've given both the AppPool AND the IUSER accounts permissions to everything.  It's a Joomla 3.1 install.

Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Can you please state which version of joomla? Also there is a specific iis help forum on http://forum.joomla.org.

Comment: @Elin as I mention in the question it's 3.1